# ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 2) for update method in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Looking this up there are a lot of people with the same problem but none are fixing my issue. I'm fairly new to rails so this is probably something small I'm missing.

I get the following error 'ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)'

When I run the command

```
Game.find(12).game_categories(55).update(approved_by: 1)
```

I'm passing the approved_by key and the value (integer) 1 but it wont work.

I tried this from another post I found

```
Game.find(12).game_categories(55).update(approved_by, 1)
```

But then i get the error 'NameError: undefined local variable or method `approved_by' for main:Object'

game is associated with game_categories with has_many and the approved_by column is definitely there.

Creating a new game_category works fine with the command

```
Game.find(1).game_categories.create!(name:  'category name')
```

But I cant update the attributes.

Whats going on?

**EDIT:**

I just want to update the one record (column 'approved_by' in the 'game_categories' table with the id 55.

Comment: Do you want to update all the records with `game_categories(55)` ?

Comment: What do you want to achive by passing 55 as a parameter to the association?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Game.find(12).game_categories(55)
```

returns relation of records, not single record. So in order to update all game_categories of game with id 12 you can use

```
Game.find(12).game_categories(55).update_all(approved_by: 1)
```

Comment: Ok so how do i update just game_category with id 55?

Comment: ```Game.find(12).game_categories.find(55).update(approved_by: 1)```
or just
```GameCategory.find(55).update(approved_by: 1)```

Comment: Thanks the second .find was missing!